# How to change the image displayed in a JLabel without a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to write a program to play chess and I am having problems with the UI.

The display is really simple. A big `JLabel` that shows the current state of the chessboard occupies almost all of the window. Below it, in the same line, there are: a `JLabel` indicating what player must move, a `JTextArea` where he/she can write the move, a `JButton` to press when the player wants to submit the move.

There is a single event handled, the pressing of the `JButton`: when the button is pressed, the program excutes the move (not displayed because of SSCCE), creates a new image of the chessboard as it currently is, modifies the big `JLabel` to show the new image.

The reloading of the image is contained in the method `reloadImage()`. This method, among other things, calls the method `setIcon()` for the big `JLabel`: this in turn returns the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at chess.ChessUI.reloadImage(ChessUI.java:145)
```

Anybody can help me?

---

SSCCE code snippet:

```
public class ChessUI extends JFrame {

    // Swing fields

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2194112668235114615L;

    // Swing fields

    /** The greater {@link JPanel}.             */
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /** The {@link ChessBoard} image.           */
    private JLabel boardImage;
    /** The {@link ImageIcon} used in displaying the image. */
    private Icon icon;

    /** The text "Player moves".                */
    private JLabel playerIndicator;
    /** The {@link JTextField} where the player can insert the move.    */
    private JTextField moveTextField;
    /** The {@link JButton} for submitting a {@link ChessMove}.         */
    private JButton submitButton;

    // Chess fields

//  private ChessBoard board;
//  private ChessImageCreator imgCreator;

    private boolean whiteMoves = true;

    public String path = "D:\\ChessProgram\\Board.jpg";
    public String path2 = "D:\\ChessProgram\\test.png";

    // =========================================================            
        // TODO | Constructors


    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ChessUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, resolutionWidth, resolutionHeight);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
//      contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(margin, margin, margin, margin));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        // Text
        this.playerIndicator = new JLabel(" White moves. Insert move:");
        playerIndicator.setBounds(0, imageResolution + margin, textWidth, buttonHeight);
        contentPane.add(playerIndicator);

        // Move field
        moveTextField = new JTextField();
        moveTextField.setBounds(textWidth + margin, imageResolution + margin, moveWidth, buttonHeight);
        contentPane.add(moveTextField);
        moveTextField.setColumns(10);

        // Submit button
        submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
        submitButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {         }
            }   );
        submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // Acquire the input move
            //  ChessMove move = new ChessMove(moveTextField.getText(), board);

                // If the move is acceptable...
            //  if( move.isValid(board.errorManager()) )
                if( true )      // the condition has been changed to ensure the minimallity of the code example 
                    {
                    // ...executes it...
                //  board.move(move);
                    reloadImage();
                    // ...changes the player...
                    whiteMoves = ! whiteMoves;
                    // ...and corrects the text specifying who can move.
                    playerIndicator.setText(" " + (whiteMoves ? "White" : "Black") + " moves. Insert move: ");

                    }
                // If the move is invalid, the ErrorManager will act inside the call of the method .isValid()

            }
        }   );
        submitButton.setBounds(resolutionWidth - buttonWidth - 2*margin, imageResolution + margin, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        contentPane.add(submitButton);


        // Chess management
    //  this.board  = new ChessBoard();
    //  this.imgCreator     = new ChessImageCreator(board);

        // ChessBoard image
    //  imgCreator.createImage(imageResolution/StdDraw.scale(), path);
        icon = new ImageIcon(path);
        JLabel lblImage = new JLabel(icon);

//      lblImage.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        lblImage.setBounds(0, 0, imageResolution, imageResolution);
        contentPane.add(lblImage);

    }


    // =========================================================            
        // TODO | Graphic methods

    public void reloadImage() {
        // Recreate the image
    //  imgCreator.createImage(imageResolution/StdDraw.scale(), path);  

        // Reload the image
        icon = new ImageIcon(path2);        // Chosen path2 because of SSCCE
        if( icon == null )      System.out.println("ICON IS NULL");
        boardImage.setIcon(icon);   // THIS LINE CAUSES EXCEPTION
    }

    // =========================================================            
        // TODO | Graphic setting

    /** The number of pixels between the image of the {@link ChessBoard} and the {@link JFrame}, 
     * and the number of pixels between the image and the interactive {@link JButton}.              */
    public int margin = defaultMargin;

    /** The width and height of the image of the {@link ChessBoard}.            */
    public int imageResolution = defaultImageWidth;

    /** The width of the window in pixel.                                       */
    public int resolutionWidth = imageResolution + 2*margin;

    /** The height of the interactive {@link JButton} in pixel.                 */
    public int buttonHeight = defaultButtonHeight;
    /** The width of the interactive {@link JButton} in pixel.                  */
    public int buttonWidth = defaultButtonWidth;
    /** The width of the text "Player moves" in pixel.                          */
    public int textWidth = defaultTextWidth;
    /** The width of the field where the user can insert his/her {@link Move}.  */
    public int moveWidth = resolutionWidth-4*margin-textWidth-buttonWidth;

    /** The height of the window in pixel.                                      */
    public int resolutionHeight = imageResolution + 2*margin + 3*buttonHeight;  

    /** The width of the window in pixel.                                       */
//  public int resolutionWidth = defaultFrameWidth;

    /** The width and height of the image of the {@link ChessBoard}.            */
//  public int imageResolution = resolutionWidth - 2*margin;


//  public static final int defaultFrameWidth   = 612;
    public static final int defaultImageWidth   = 800;
    public static final int defaultFrameHeight  = 800;
    public static final int defaultMargin       =  10;
    public static final int defaultButtonHeight =  25;
    public static final int defaultButtonWidth  = 100;
    public static final int defaultTextWidth    = 160;


    // =========================================================            
        // TODO | Main

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ChessUI frame = new ChessUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }




}
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it. The error is in line 145 of your Java file.

Comment: Ok, you never initialised `boardImage`, that's why.

Comment: 1) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556) 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and ..

Comment: .. borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) That's not a valid SSCCE. It does not include imports (so is not SC), and includes too much redundant code. It also refers to images on your file system, but not ours.. 4) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Comment: 5) BTW: There is no such thing as 'JSwing'. Swing API *components* are prefixed with a `J` to distinguish them from the AWT equivalents, but the J is not in the toolkit name.